# Why the :attribute_check in Declarative_Authorization don't found ID's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, declarative-authorization

I have a problem since many days with Declarative_Authorization on Ruby on Rails 3.1.
I add this on the top of each controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    # Verifies that the user is connected and/or authorized to access the methods
    filter_access_to :all, :attribute_check => true

    (...)
end
```

It allows me to have this on my `authorization_rules.rb`:

```
has_permission_on [:albums], :to => [:adding] do
    if_attribute :group => { :user => is { user } }
end
```

But when I add `:attribute_check => true` I get this error :

```
Couldn't find {Model} without an ID
```

I'm totally lost, I was starting with this gem.

Answer (score 0):

Your user variable is null maybe, so find the error why its null

Comment: Even if user variable is set I got this error. And the message could be : Couldn't find Photo without an ID. The message is display for each Model.

Comment: I got a module in lib directory name : `authorizations.rb`. This Authorization class have en instance variable @user. I only have to write `Authorization.current_user = current_user` to set the variable. The gem have a method current_user that set the variable @user. Do you know this gem ? It's a very difficult gem to understand...

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick, just add this on the top of the controller :

```
class Group
    before_filter :set_group
    (...)
    protected
    def set_group
        @group = Group.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    end
end
```